# Expected value of $X^3$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value

> Let $X$ be a random variable with uniform distribution in [0,1]. Find the expected value of $X^3$.

$E(X)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} x f_X dx$, because $X$ has a uniform distribution, then $X^3$ also has a uniform distribution. Then $f_{X^3}(x)=\frac{1}{b-a}$ when $a<x<b$ with $a=0$ and $b=1$, then $f_{X^3}(x)=1 \Rightarrow E(X^3)=\int\limits_{0}^{1} xdx=1$  (which is wrong)

I know that mistake is somewhere when finding $f_{X^3}(x)$

The correct answer is

> $$E(X^3)=\frac{1}{4}$$

Comment: "because $X$ has a uniform distribution, then $X^3$ also has a uniform distribution" is incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X\sim f_X(x)$, then

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}\left[X\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}xf_X(x)dx \\
\mathbf{E}\left[g(X)\right] &= \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}g(x)f_X(x)dx, \text{for some function }g(x).
\end{aligned}
$$

In your case, $X\sim Uniform(0, 1)\Rightarrow f_X(x) = 1, x ∈ [0, 1]$, and $g(x) = x^3 \Rightarrow$

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{E}\left[X^3\right] &= \int_{0}^{1}x^3dx = \left.\frac{x^4}{4}\right|_0^1 = \frac{1}{4}.
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1):

> I know that mistake is somewhere when finding $f_{X^3}(x)$

Take some uniformly spread sample points, say $\{0.00,0.25,0.50,0.75,1.00\}$, and examine their cubes, $\{0, 0.015625, 0.125, 0.421875, 1\}$.  The cubes are concentrated towards $0$ , so $X^3$ is clearly not uniformly distributed.

Indeed, by taking the derivative of the cumulative distribution function we find the probability density function is:

$$\begin{align}f_{X^3}(x)&=\dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm dx}\mathsf P(X^3\leq x)\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d~~}{\mathrm dx}\mathsf P(X\leq x^{1/3})\\&=\dfrac{\mathrm d x^{1/3}}{\mathrm d x~~~~}\mathbf 1_{x\in(0..1]}\\&=\tfrac 13 x^{-2/3}\mathbf 1_{x\in[0..1]}\end{align}$$

So $$\mathsf E(X^3)~{=\int_\Bbb R s~f_{X^3}(s)\,\mathrm d s\\=\int_0^1 \tfrac 13 s^{1/3}\,\mathrm d s\\= \tfrac 14}$$

---

Or, the easier method, by the so called Law of the Unconscious Statistician: $$\mathsf E(X^3)~{=\int_\Bbb R x^3 f_X(x)\,\mathrm d x\\=\int_0^1 x^3\,\mathrm d x\\=\tfrac 14}$$

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're trying the "calculus route", however, when dealing with expectation of a variable with an exponent that is greater than 2, using [Moment Generating Functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) would be easier.

Here's a helpful [link](http://www.milefoot.com/math/stat/rv-moments.htm) if you want to try this approach.